# incidence matrix for bipartite groups with multiple joins

Tags: r, matrix, graph, adjacency-matrix, bipartite

I was wondering if there's a fast way to get an incidence matrix for this such a problem. I've got two data frames with three columns (the join keys)

```
df1 <- data.frame(K1=c(1,1,0,1,3,2,2),K2=c(1,2,1,0,2,0,1),K3=c(0,0,3,2,1,3,0))
df2 <- data.frame(K1=c(1,2,0,3),K2=c(0,1,2,0),K3=c(2,0,3,1))
```

and I need to obtain the corresponding incidence matrix

```
# IM:
#   1 2 3 4
# 1 1 1 0 0
# 2 1 0 1 0
# 3 0 1 1 0
# 4 1 0 0 0
# 5 0 0 1 1
# 6 0 1 1 0
# 7 0 1 0 0
```

where it's set `1` if there's a match between the corresponding `KEY` (column value) of rows of the two data frames.
I would do by using multiple loops

```
for (j in seq_len(nrow(df2)))
  for (k in seq_len(ncol(df2))) {
    if (df2[j,k])
      m[which(df1[,k] == df2[j,k]),j] <- 1
  }
```

but it's a C approach and maybe there's something faster in R. Do you have any other ideas? Besides, when the data.frame are quite big (around 50k and 20k rows), I cannot allocate the matrix as it seems too big.

Comment: Can you please show the for loop that generates this output?

Comment: sure! see the update